# Wifi device not being detected in Ubuntu

Tags: networking

When trying to connect using my built in wifi adapter, Ubuntu does not see it. However, it's being somewhat detected because it appears in a lspci log - shown below.

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b024]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at c0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: r8822be
```

Could someone explain to me what is going on and if possible, what action I could take to fix this?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? What is the model of the wifi adapter?

Comment: Where did you get this `r8822be`? Did you install some driver?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.4.2. I'm almost certain that the model of the adapter is RTL8822BE by Realtek. It's the original that came in my ThinkPad. I've read that it's a pretty crappy adapter, but I can't even get "crappy", I just get nothing.

Comment: And no, I did not install any specific drivers